# AngularJS Recursion in html table

Tags: angularjs, html

ok i have this code:

```
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Amount
                </th>
                <th>
                    Period
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-ng-repeat="expense in expenses">
            <tr class="danger">
                <td>
                    <button data-ng-if="expense.Children.length > 0 && expense.ShowChildren" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="expense.ShowChildren = false">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
                    </button>
                    <button data-ng-if="expense.Children.length > 0 && !expense.ShowChildren" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="expense.ShowChildren = true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    {{ expense.Description }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ expense.Amount }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ expense.Period }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active" ng-show="expense.ShowChildren" data-ng-repeat="child in expense.Children">
                <td>
                    &emsp;&ensp;&emsp;&ensp;{{ child.Description }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    &emsp;&ensp;&emsp;&ensp;{{ child.Amount }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    &emsp;&ensp;&emsp;&ensp;{{ child.Period }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

[image: and this the view]

now i want to expense can have a child like u see in the photo
and this is work but when the child have child how I display that ?
i want to do the plus/minus button

Comment: can use `ng-repeat-start` combined with `ng-repeat-end`. Put child details in row created with `ng-repeat-end`

Comment: but how its I write it when i want to show the Childrens of one of the child for example if Books have a child 
how I do it ?

Comment: using nested `ng-repeat` in `ng-repeat-end` row

Comment: u can write me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a table from swimlane with much success lately. This is a feature that they support. This table is available here.

http://swimlane.github.io/angular-data-table/

You can do it, but you basically have to use expressions that insert the buttons where appropriate and ng-show/css to hide and display the rows when the buttons are clicked and a lot of other manual work.

Comment: i found the tree table option ty :D

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy way to do it

```
Tree View: http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/
```

its better then other ways and more simple